# Google map api javascript for address auto filling is not working (InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am using google map api for address auto fill in my ruby on rails app.In two forms I have used the address auto fill .But only in one form its working fine.

### Working code

### new.html.erb in location

```
 <%= form_for @location,url: locations_path,html: {method: 'post'}  do |f| %>
<div class="form_format">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :address %>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :locality %>
        <%= f.text_field :locality, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control",readonly: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div></div>
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"><center>                

        <%= f.submit 'Add Details', class: "btn btn-primary" %></center>
    </div>  
</div>
```

### working js

```js
var placeSearch, location_address;
var address=[];
var componentForm = {
  formatted_address: 'location_address',
  sublocality_level_1: 'location_locality',
  locality: 'location_city',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'location_state',
  country: 'location_country'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  location_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                      (document.getElementById('location_address')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  location_address.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

}

function fillInAddress() {
 address=[];
  var place = location_address.getPlace();
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i]['long_name'];
      document.getElementById(componentForm[addressType]).value = val;
      
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      location_address.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

### Not Working code

### edit.html.erb in doctorinfo

```
<%= form_for @doctorinfo,url: doctorinfo_path(@doctorinfo),html: {method: 'patch',multipart: true}  do |f| %>
<div class="form_format">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :address %>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :locality %>
        <%= f.text_field :locality, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control",readonly: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div></div>
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control",
        readonly: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :specialization %>
        <%= f.text_field :specialization, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :time_per_slot %>
        <%= f.text_field :time_per_slot, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="star">*</div>
        <%= f.label :fees %>
        <%= f.text_field :fees, class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
    <p>
    <label>Profile Picture:</label>
    <% if @doctorinfo.profile?%>
        <%= image_tag (@doctorinfo.profile_url), class: 'profile' %>
    <% end%>    
    <%= f.file_field :profile %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :profile_cache %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>
      <%= f.check_box :remove_profile %>
      Remove Picture
    </label>
  </p>      
    <div class="form-group"><center>                
        <%= f.submit 'Update Details', class: "btn btn-primary" , name: "saving"%></center>
    </div>  
</div>
```

<% end %>

### Not working js

```js
var placeSearch, doctorinfo_address;
var address=[];
var componentForm = {
  formatted_address: 'doctorinfo_address',
  sublocality_level_1: 'doctorinfo_locality',
  locality: 'doctorinfo_city',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'doctorinfo_state',
  country: 'doctorinfo_country'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  doctorinfo_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                      (document.getElementById('doctorinfo_address')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  doctorinfo_address.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
 address=[];
  var place = doctorinfo_address.getPlace();
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i]['long_name'];
      document.getElementById(componentForm[addressType]).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      doctorinfo_address.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

And when I check the console in the browser the error is

> InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

What am I doing wrong?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem .I was placing the js files in the assets/javascripts folder.So it was causing ambiguity .The problem resolved by adding the js files in its respective view.Hope it saves someone's time.